# How to define counters with arbitrary alphabet

Tags: counters

I need to define counters using fractur fonts and **hebrew** alphabet.
For the greek alphabet I'm using the package [engrec](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/engrec).
Any suggestion?
Thanks

Comment: You can use the \ifcase construction (which is how \alph does it).

Comment: @JohnKormylo, thanks for the prompt reply, but, being a sort of newbie, could you elaborate a little further?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What John Kormylo probably [meant](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/529813/how-to-define-counters-with-arbitrary-alphabet#comment1339950_529813) is that, if it is reasonable to enumerate all cases that can possibly occur, you can paraphrase the definition of `\alph` in LaTeX, which relies on TeX's `\ifcase` conditional as follows:

```latex
\def\alph#1{\expandafter\@alph\csname c@#1\endcsname}

\def\@alph#1{%
  \ifcase#1\or a\or b\or c\or d\or e\or f\or g\or h\or i\or j\or
   k\or l\or m\or n\or o\or p\or q\or r\or s\or t\or u\or v\or w\or x\or
    y\or z\else\@ctrerr\fi}
```

For instance, the following is a dumb way to format a LaTeX counter using the famous (?) [Shadok](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Les_Shadoks) numeral system. This is a  base-4 positional numeral system where the available symbols for each digit are Ga = 0, Bu = 1, Zo = 2 and Meu = 3.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgffor}     % only for the demo code
\usepackage{multicol}   % only for the demo code

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\@shadokNumber}[1]{%
  \ifcase #1% #1 is supposed to be a <number>
        Ga\or      Bu\or      Zo\or      Meu\or
      BuGa\or    BuBu\or    BuZo\or    BuMeu\or
      ZoGa\or    ZoBu\or    ZoZo\or    ZoMeu\or
     MeuGa\or   MeuBu\or   MeuZo\or   MeuMeu\or
    BuGaGa\or  BuGaBu\or  BuGaZo\or  BuGaMeu\or
    BuBuGa\or  BuBuBu\or  BuBuZo\or  BuBuMeu\or
    BuZoGa\or  BuZoBu\or  BuZoZo\or  BuZoMeu\or
   BuMeuGa\or BuMeuBu\or BuMeuZo\or BuMeuMeu\or
    ZoGaGa\or  ZoGaBu\or  ZoGaZo\or  ZoGaMeu\or
    ZoBuGa\or  ZoBuBu\or  ZoBuZo\or  ZoBuMeu\or
    ZoZoGa\or  ZoZoBu\or  ZoZoZo\or  ZoZoMeu\or
   ZoMeuGa\or ZoMeuBu\or ZoMeuZo\or ZoMeuMeu\or
   MeuGaGa\or  MeuGaBu\or  MeuGaZo\or  MeuGaMeu\or
   MeuBuGa\or  MeuBuBu\or  MeuBuZo\or  MeuBuMeu\or
   MeuZoGa\or  MeuZoBu\or  MeuZoZo\or  MeuZoMeu\or
  MeuMeuGa\or MeuMeuBu\or MeuMeuZo\or MeuMeuMeu\or BuGaGaGa% = 64 in decimal
  % etc.
  \else \@ctrerr \fi
}

\newcommand*{\shadokNumber}[1]{%
  \expandafter\@shadokNumber\csname c@#1\endcsname
}
\makeatother

\newcounter{myctr}

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{3}
  \noindent
  \foreach \i in {0,...,64} {%
    \shadokNumber{myctr}\\
    \stepcounter{myctr}%
  }%
  etc.
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

[image]

## Generalization (positional numeral systems)

Regular positional numeral systems can be handled with generic code. What follows borrows from the `expl3` implementation of `\int_to_base:nn` and adapts it in order to provide formatting of arbitrary integers in the Shadok numeral system. The available symbols for digits here are still `Ga`, `Bu`, `Zo` and `Meu` (several tokens each), but you can replace them with any LaTeX code of your choice. Just don't forget to update the number of available symbols in `\g_guidone_nb_symbols_int` (here: 4).

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{multicol}   % only for the demo code

\ExplSyntaxOn
% Ga, Bu, Zo, Meu: 4 symbols. Replace with the number of digit symbols you have.
\int_const:Nn \c_guidone_nb_shadok_digit_symbols_int { 4 }

% Replace Ga, Bu, Zo, Meu with LaTeX code producing each possible digit symbol.
\cs_new:Npn \__guidone_to_shadok_digit:n #1
  {
    \exp_after:wN \__guidone_remove_fi:nw
    \if_case:w #1 \c_space_token  % this finishes the <number>
      { Ga }
    \or:
      { Bu }
    \or:
      { Zo }
    \or:
      { Meu }
    \else:
      { \msg_expandable_error:nnn { guidone } { too-large-for-a-digit } {#1} }
    \fi:
  }

\msg_new:nnn { guidone } { too-large-for-a-digit }
  { Too~large~for~a~digit:~\exp_not:n {#1}. }

% Define aliases that can be used outside \ExplSyntaxOn ... \ExplSyntaxOff.
\cs_new_eq:NN \nbShadokDigitSymbols \c_guidone_nb_shadok_digit_symbols_int
\cs_new_eq:NN \toShadokDigit \__guidone_to_shadok_digit:n

% The \exp_stop_f: stops f-expansion from the \__guidone_deliver:nfw call.
% \__guidone_to_digit:n should normally be used within f-expansion,
% otherwise the \exp_stop_f: (implicit space token) will precede the wanted
% result (digit).
\cs_new:Npn \__guidone_remove_fi:nw #1#2\fi:
  { \fi: \exp_stop_f: #1 }

% #1: base (= number of available digit symbols)
% #2: function such as \__guidone_to_shadok_digit:n (input: a number between 0
%     and #1 - 1, both inclusive; output: a single digit)
% #3: number to format
\cs_new:Npn \guidone_format_number:nNn #1#2#3
  {
    \exp:w
    \__guidone_to_base:nnN {#3} {#1} #2
    \q_stop
  }

% The \*_to_base:* functions are based on code from l3int.dtx, with
% modifications so that \guidone_format_number:nNn can deliver potentially
% sensitive material with \exp_not:n in exactly two expansion steps.
\cs_new:Npn \__guidone_to_base:nnN #1
  { \exp_args:Nf \__guidone_to_base_aux:nnN { \int_eval:n {#1} } }

\cs_new:Npn \__guidone_to_base_aux:nnN #1#2#3
  {
    \int_compare:nNnTF {#1} < { 0 }
      { \exp_args:No \__guidone_to_base:nnnN { \use_none:n #1 } {#2} { - } #3 }
      { \__guidone_to_base:nnnN {#1} {#2} { } #3 }
  }

% #1: empty or minus sign
% #2: leftmost digit of the number (i.e., the last digit produced by
%     \guidone_format_number:nNn)
% #3: the remaining digits
%
% The \exp_end: terminates the expansion started by \exp:w in
% \guidone_format_number:nNn.
\cs_new:Npn \__guidone_deliver:nnw #1#2#3\q_stop
  { \exp_end: \exp_not:n { #1#2#3 } }

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__guidone_deliver:nnw { nf }

\cs_new:Npn \__guidone_to_base:nnnN #1#2#3#4
  {
    \int_compare:nNnTF {#1} < {#2}
      { \__guidone_deliver:nfw {#3} { #4 {#1} } }
      {
        \exp_args:Nf \__guidone_to_base:nnnnN
          { #4 { \int_mod:nn {#1} {#2} } }
          {#1}
          {#2}
          {#3}
          #4
      }
  }

\cs_new:Npn \__guidone_to_base:nnnnN #1#2#3#4#5
  {
    \exp_args:Nf \__guidone_to_base:nnnN
      { \int_div_truncate:nn {#2} {#3} }
      {#3}
      {#4}
      #5
    #1
  }

% Define aliases that can be used outside \ExplSyntaxOn ... \ExplSyntaxOff.
% Note that \guideoneFormatNumber is fully expandable and delivers the result
% in two expansion steps.
\cs_new_eq:NN \guideoneFormatNumber \guidone_format_number:nNn
\cs_new_eq:NN \intstepinline \int_step_inline:nnnn
\ExplSyntaxOff

% What follows \shadokNumber in the input stream will be the third argument of
% \guideoneFormatNumber, i.e.: the number to convert.
\newcommand*{\shadokNumber}{%
  \guideoneFormatNumber{\nbShadokDigitSymbols}{\toShadokDigit}%
}

\newcounter{myctr}

% Make it so that \themyctr uses our custom numeration style.
\renewcommand{\themyctr}{%
  \shadokNumber{\value{myctr}}%
}


\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{3}
  \noindent
  % Initial value, step, final value
  \intstepinline{0}{1}{64}{%
    \themyctr\\
    \stepcounter{myctr}%
  }%
  etc.
\end{multicols}

Most importantly:
\[ 65536 = \shadokNumber{65536} \]
and  % We can handle any 〈integer expression〉, including negative ones.
\[ -(3\times 64 + 2\times 16 + 1\times 4 + 0\times 1) =
   \shadokNumber{-1*(3*64 + 2*16 + 1*4 + 0*1)} \]

% Verify that the desired result is obtained in exactly two expansion steps.
% If you uncomment the following seven lines, TeX will print on the terminal:
%   > \exp_not:n {-MeuZoBuGa}.
%
% \def\zzz#1{\expandafter\showtokens\expandafter{#1}}
% \expandafter\zzz\expandafter{%
%   \guideoneFormatNumber
%     {\nbShadokDigitSymbols}
%     {\toShadokDigit}
%     {-1*(3*64 + 2*16 + 1*4 + 0*1)}%
% }

\end{document}
```

[image]

As you can see from the following definition:

```latex
\newcommand*{\shadokNumber}{%
  \guideoneFormatNumber{\nbShadokDigitSymbols}{\toShadokDigit}%
}
```

the only thing you need to do in order to define conversion functions for other numeral systems in the same document is to pass `\guideoneFormatNumber`:

- the number of available digit symbols, i.e. the *base* (`\nbShadokDigitSymbols` is 4 in our example);
- a function such as `\toShadokDigit` (i.e., `\__guidone_to_shadok_digit:n`) that converts a number between 0 and *base* - 1 to its 1-digit representation in the destination numeral system.

The number to convert has to come next in the input stream and doesn't need to be grabbed as an argument by `\shadokNumber` (this is a small optimization).

## Hebrew numeration

Hebrew numeration seems to be less regular than what the above code is designed to handle. If only a small number of values are needed, you can use the first approach. Otherwise, I'm afraid you'll need another conversion algorithm. The `polyglossia` package provides commands such as `\hebrewnumeral`, `\Hebrewnumeral` and `\Hebrewnumeralfinal` that might be of interest to you. You might be interested in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/300008/modify-specific-hebrew-alpha-numerals-on-page-number) for instance. Alas, I don't know Hebrew, so can't help you more in this area.

Comment: thank you very much for your exhaustive answer. Just what I needed.

Comment: You're welcome. :-) You may want to check the updated answer: I made the interface a bit more flexible in the second piece of code.

Answer (score 3):

With `babel` 3.41, just released, comes a bunch of predefined additive and alphabetic numerals for some languages, based on the CSS [ready-made counter styles](https://www.w3.org/TR/predefined-counter-styles/) (numeric styles have been available since `babel` 3.20). More importantly, they are defined with the help of a set of key/value pairs in `ini` files, which means you can define your own styles with `\babelprovide`, too. Note this tool is meant for `xetex` and `luatex`, but it *may* work in `pdftex`. Here is an example with some explanations.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[italian]{babel}

\babelprovide[
     % To define a purely alphabetic numeral, just provide a space-
     % separated list of ordered symbols, characters, etc. Let's name
     % it 'lower' (you can choose another name):
  counters/lower=Aa Bb Cc Dd Ee Ff Gg Hh Ii Jj Kk Ll,
     % For additive numerals, a set of four keys are required, numbered
     % with a digit from 1 (for 1-9) to 4 (for 1000-9000) preceded by a
     % dot. Let's name it 'letters':
  counters/letters.1= a b c d e f g h i,
  counters/letters.2= k l m n o p q r s, 
  counters/letters.3= A B C D E F G H I,
  counters/letters.4= K L M N O P Q R S,
     % Fixed representations for specific values of additive numerals
     % are allowed, too. Just end the key with dot, uppercase F, dot,
     % number:
  counters/letters.F.55 = Oohh
     % Redefining \alph to print these numerals is simple:
  alph = letters    
  ]{italian}

\begin{document}

\localenumeral{lower}{4}     % Prints Dd

\localenumeral{lower}{2}     % Prints Bb

\localenumeral{letters}{956} % Prints Iof

\localenumeral{letters}{55}  % Prints Oohh

\alph{page}  % Prints a, because it's the first page and \alph uses the
             % 'letters' numerals

\end{document}
```

For further details, see [What's new in babel 3.41](https://github.com/latex3/babel/wiki/What's-new-in-babel-3.41).